# How do I accumulate 50 points?

Tags: discussion

I seek an answer to a question about my account.

It says that I can not comment on an entry until I have 50 points. How do I accumulate said points?

Comment: By posting answers  to questions that are voted up to give you enough rep. But please don't post comments as answers to get round it - that won't do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it isn't about English.

Comment: Please take the **[tour]** of the site, and if you're still unsure, see the Help Centre's page on [What's Reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This isn't always obvious, but you often need to *scroll down* to see the actual answers to questions; what you see just after the question are only "comments". Anyone can post a full answer to most questions, regardless of points, which is how you get reputation. So if you have a good answer to a question, scroll down to the bottom of the page and write it in the box where it says "Your Answer". (I'm posting this as a comment because if you don't know to scroll down, you won't see it in the answer section on the other question.)

Comment: Basically, you gain points when others here "upvote" questions or answers that you authored.  You need a certain number of points (I'm thinking 50) to be able to comment on the questions or answers of others (though you do not need the points to comment on your own questions or answers).